# Сортировка подмножество std::vector через другой std::vector

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм, stl

Как можно отсортировать определенные индексы в std::vector, используя другой std::vector?

Например, у меня есть std::vector, который хранить в себе int'ы. Теперь я выбираю из него только чётные индексы и помещаю их в std::vector< std::reference_wrapper< int > >. На данный момент, я предполагаю, что второй vector хранит в себе "ссылку" на элементы первого. Далее я произвожу сортировку в надежде на то, что и в пером векторе четные индексы будут отсортированы, однако этого не происходит.

Возможно, я плохо объяснил, поэтому приведу пример кода:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T>
void printVector(const std::vector<T>& vector)
{
    for (const auto& el : vector)
        std::cout << el << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{

    std::vector<int> vector = {7,5,1,3,2};
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>> vector_ref({vector[0], vector[2], vector[4]});

    printVector(vector_ref); // получаем 7 1 2
    printVector(vector);     // получаем 7 5 1 3 2

    std::sort(vector_ref.begin(), vector_ref.end()); // сортирую vector_ref в надежде, что эта сортировка затронет элементы vector.

    printVector(vector_ref); // получаем 1 2 7, как и ожидалось.
    printVector(vector);     // получаем 7 5 1 3 2, а ожидалось 1 5 2 3 7. То есть 0,2 и 4 индекс должны были быть отсортированы.

    return 0;
}
```

Если через std::reference_wrapper это сделать невозможно, то какие есть еще варианты?

Comment: Через вектор ссылок не получится - у вас в этом векторе меняются местами, грубо говоря, указатели на элементы (врапперы, заменяющие ссылки), а не то, на что они указывают.

Comment: @Harry , а есть вариант, как можно реализовать подобную штуку?

Comment: Если вас не пугает память O(n) (ну, в `vector_ref` не пугала же...) — то, например, скопировать все четные элементы в новый вектор, отсортировать, вернуть назад в новом порядке. Или написать свою сортировку. Поскольку с `ranges` я не разбирался, не знаю — но, может, там тоже есть такая возможность?...